# How to add a sockethandler to logcat on a 2013 nexus 7 with android 6.0.1?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-logcat, nexus-7

doing something naive like:

```
SocketHandler socketHandler=new SocketHandler(host,service);
socketHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
Logger global=Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
global.addHandler(socketHandler);
```

does not seems to work.

edit: global.severe("foo") does work. but the rest of the logcat messages do not appear.

i would like all (or most) of the logcat messages to go to the log server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need [LogRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html), see example below:

```
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("concrete.log");

    Handler handle = new SocketHandler("localhost", 8080);

    LogRecord logRec = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "Log will be recorded");

    handle.publish(logRec);

    handle.setFormatter(new XMLFormatter());

    logger.addHandler(handle);

    logger.info("socket handler info message");
```

Comment: logger.log does a publish to all handlers.